# Trying to plot around 10 lines and name each line differently?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have collected read and write information on filesystems:

- vfs, ext4 layer and trying to visualize it using matplotlib trough pyplot.

I wanted to add a label for each line but I can't.
The code as well as the result is given below.

````
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import csv
    vrc=0
    erc=0
    vwc=0
    ewc=0
    with open('graph.csv','r') as csvfile :
        rows = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))[1:]
        rows.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[6]))
        for row in rows:
            if (int(row[6])>65536):
                print(row[6]+'\n')
            if (row[5]=='VR'):
                vrc=vrc+1
            elif (row[5]=='ER'):
                erc=erc+1
            elif (row[5]=='VW'):
                vwc=vwc+1
            elif (row[5]=='EW'):
                ewc=ewc+1
            start, end, data = int(row[0]), int(row[1]), int(row[6])
            x = [start, end]
            y = [data, data]
            plt.plot(x, y, label=row[2]+row[5], marker='o')
    plt.xlabel('time(milliseconds)')
    plt.ylabel('Amount of Data(bytes)')
    plt.title('VFS and EXT4 layer READ/WRITE graph')
plt.legend(['VR = Red, ER=black, VW=blue, EW=green, vr=%d, er=%d, vw=%d,ew=%d' % (vrc,erc,vwc,ewc)])
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig('test.png')
    plt.show()```


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD6I4.png
````

Comment: Hello,  maybe a bit late - but better late than never, I suppose?  Anyway,  on line 25 I see a syntax error (Correct me if I'm wrong) I couldn't run the above code anyway, in Jupyter. Fixed with a Edit - try and re-post the results, and let's see how it goes. I'll be here :)  //Best luck!

Comment: forgot, 1 thing: could you post the csv file, so others can try themselves? Thanks.

Comment: It was my project which I was working on last year, it may take some time to retrieve the csv file. I will definitely make changes as I find the files, Thanks for your support!

Comment: I have changed line 25. I found the csv file but I don't know how to upload it here, any ideas?

Comment: Reply: "Thanks for your support" No problem at all. I am glad I can be of any help, at all.

Hello, sorry for the delay, - you can (if it's not **too big**) maybe format it down & paste it in your post?  Or, if it is big, - upload it  (If it's not private!, or sensitive) - via maybe (Note! I have not used any of those sites, but - if it's not private information it *should* be okay) https://tmpfiles.org/ maybe could work? and then obviously share the link. If it is too big for that website, maybe try to zip it with e.g 7z and try again. :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nb45gMcjqGxPAqR5l_ARxwOCJBm2IQZ_/view?usp=sharing tmpfiles.org is not accepting csv files, I shared on my drive, try to download it. No sensitive info at all.

Comment: matplotlib was there, I think editor error, Now inserted from the new line. Added variable initialization too.

Comment: 1 question, when you say label for each line, do you mean on each "dot" or *exactly* where do you want the labels?

Comment: Either dot or line is ok.

Comment: Edit: updated; hope it was like this you expected the lines to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
vrc=0
erc=0
vwc=0
ewc=0
with open('graph.csv','r') as csvfile :
    rows = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))[1:]
    rows.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[6]))
    for row in rows:
        if (int(row[6])>65536):
            print(row[6]+'\n')
        if (row[5]=='VR'):
            vrc=vrc+1
        elif (row[5]=='ER'):
            erc=erc+1
        elif (row[5]=='VW'):
            vwc=vwc+1
        elif (row[5]=='EW'):
            ewc=ewc+1
        start, end, data = int(row[0]), int(row[1]), int(row[6])
        x = [start, end]
        y = [data, data]
        for x,y in zip(x,y):

                plt.annotate(('vr=%d, er=%d, vw=%d,ew=%d'%(vrc,erc,vwc,ewc)),(x,y),textcoords="offset points",xytext=(0,13),ha='right')
        plt.plot(x, y, marker='o')
plt.title('VFS and EXT4 layer READ/WRITE graph')
plt.legend(['VR = Red, ER=black, VW=blue, EW=green, vr=%d, er=%d, vw=%d,ew=%d' % (vrc,erc,vwc,ewc)])
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Or, if you want maybe a legend top right:

(maybe easier to read)

```
plt.legend('VR = Red, ER=black, VW=blue, EW=green, vr=%d, er=%d, vw=%d,ew=%d' % (vrc,erc,vwc,ewc))
```

[image]

Comment: I had, a bit problem with formatting - so it maybe looks weird on the code/picture.    EDIT: **I am So Happy this worked!  Good luck on this project/ and on all other things you work on! -Have a  great, corona-free year! //W.M**